# custom encryption #2

Tags: c#, encryption

I wrote a code for custom encryption. It is a challenge. Right now it doesn't work for some reasons like:

Encrypt("abc", "hello everyone")
Returns: sdfhsjfjs
Decrypt("abc", "sdfhsjfjs")
Retruns: diuifidu

```
    public int CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(string Text)
{
    int Count = 0;
    foreach (char x in Text)
    {
        Count++;
    }
    return Count - 1;
}

public int CountCharInString(string Text)
{
    int Count = 0;
    foreach (char x in Text)
    {
        Count++;
    }
    return Count;
}
public string Encrypt(string Key, string PlainText)
{
    int[] TempKey = new int[CountCharInString(Key)];
    int[] TempText = new int[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
    int[] EncryptedInt = new int[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
    char[] EncryptedChar = new char[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key); i++)
    {
        TempKey[i] = (int)Key[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(PlainText); i++)
    {
        TempText[i] = (int)PlainText[i];
    }
    int Index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(PlainText); i++)
    {
        if (Index == CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key))
        {
            Index = 0;
        }
        EncryptedInt[i] = TempKey[Index] + TempText[i];
        Index++;
        EncryptedChar[i] = (char)EncryptedInt[i];
    }
    return new string(EncryptedChar);
}

public string Decrypt(string Key, string EncryptedText)
{
    int[] TempKey = new int[CountCharInString(Key)];
    int[] TempText = new int[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
    int[] DecryptedInt = new int[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
    char[] DecryptedChar = new char[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key); i++)
    {
        TempKey[i] = (int)Key[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(EncryptedText); i++)
    {
        TempText[i] = (int)EncryptedText[i];
    }
    int Index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(EncryptedText); i++)
    {
        if (Index == CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key))
        {
            Index = 0;
        }
        DecryptedInt[i] = TempText[i] - TempKey[Index];
        Index++;
        DecryptedChar[i] = (char)DecryptedInt[i];
    }
    return new string(DecryptedChar);
}
```

Also I know that string have a length property it just I forget to correct it.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise, I strongly advise you not to write your own encryption routines.  It is *very* easy to get it wrong in ways that are not obvious.

Comment: Yes it is a learning exercise.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you shouldn't be building your own encryption scheme, `sdfhsjfjs` cannot possibly represent `hello everybody` unless you are also compressing the input data.

Comment: I wonder what programmers told Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijmen when they were creating AES encryption.

Comment: You would obviously need the patience to debug through your application. Encrypt a simple text let's say, 'Hi M' and Decrypt it while crosschecking whether it's conforming with your algorithm. It'd be easier for you than someone else trying to figure out your algorithm and debugging it for you, if you encounter a specific problem, you can come back and update it.

Comment: @Inisheer if OP has a doctorate in cryptography (as Joan and Vincent do) I will be surprised :P

Comment: your code seems working to me. except as someone already answered the length of string your returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
return Count - 1;
```

in `CountCharInStringAccordingToArray` to

```
return Count;
```

A representation of your code:

```
String That(String key, String text, int sign) {
    return new String(Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length).Select((x, i) => (char)(text.ToArray()[i]+sign*key.ToArray()[i%key.Length])).ToArray());
}

public String Encrypt(String key, String text) {
    return That(key, text, 1);
}

public String Decrypt(String key, String text) {
    return That(key, text, -1);
}
```

The principle of how it works is easy. Look at the graph:

[image: EgB5n.jpg]

The characters in the `key` are used repeatedly to add to the `text` and resulting a sequence that considered *encrypted*. The decryption is just a reverse operation by subtracting.

The maximum value can store in a byte is `0x0ff`, but the maximum value of **visible characters** is `0x7e`, that is `~`, and `0x7e+0x7e=0xfc`.

So **as long as** your key and text are in the range of visible characters, it will not cause overflowing. That is, you can decrypt the encrypted sequence to the original correctly.

Comment: Thank for the answer but i do not really get how it works. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked really well. No foibles found.

Comment: The explanation is apply to `byte[]`, with `char[]` it won't overflow in the range of a single `char` can store, which is 16 bits(2 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

[Get string length and output string](http://www.java2v.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/Getstringlengthandoutputstring.htm)

using System;

```
class MainClass {   
  public static void Main() {   
    string str1 = "ABCDEabcde1234567890";   

    Console.WriteLine("str1: " + str1); 

    Console.WriteLine("Length of str1: " + str1.Length);   
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be?

Comment: @Miky Dinescu Notice that the OP used a custom method... to get the length of a string.

Comment: I did. But how is this answer supposed to help with the actual question? That's what I don't get..

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I actually think this answer point out the POINT - `String.Length`.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"www.java2v.com’s server IP address could not be found."*